# mail to function not working mobile devices?

Tags: email, html-email

i have use mail to html code. this code will be all browser and ipad is working fine. but mobile devices not working.

```
<a href="mailto:?Subject=title&amp;Body=content"><img alt="Email" src="images/mail.gif"></a>
```

thanks for your future help!

Comment: You may have better success asking the question at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=title&amp;body=content">
    <img alt="Email" src="images/mail.gif">
</a>
```

try subject and body in lower-cases and it will work.